# Laravel dynamically populating a list of checkbox from database

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, checkbox, dynamic

I have a **categories model** that `belongsToMany` **methodologies** and the **methodologies** has also many **categories** so meaning it has a **many to many relationship**.

In my view I have a dropdown of **categories** and when I select one it will populate a **list of checkbox** base from that specific **category**.

In my **categories model**

```
public function methodology()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Methodologies')->withTimestamps();;
    }
```

and in my **methodologies model**

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Categories')->withTimestamps();;
    }
```

The relationship is working fine and tested.

Now I have this `function or method` in my **ajax**

```
$(function() {
            $('select[name=category_id]').change(function() {

                let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';

                $.get(url2, function(data) {
                    let select2 = $('form select[name= methodology_id]');

                    select2.empty();

                    $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                        console.log(key + ' '+ value);
                        select2.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

So what the ajax function does it when I select some **category** in the **category drop down**, it populates my **methodology drop down** which is working well.

But I want to change my **methodology dropdown** into a list of checkbox that can check multiple checkbox?

Here's my code in my **view**

```
div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="methodology_id" id="methodology_ud" class="minimal">
    </label>
</div>
```

The code above is a former dropdown below

```
{{-- <label for="methodology_id">Method:</label> --}}
    {{-- <select  name="methodology_id" class="form-control" required id="methodology_id">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Method</option>
    </select> --}}
```

But what I want to happen is to change the dropdown into checkbox that can check multiple item and store it to my db. Which I couldn't achieve it in my ajax and html code.

Can someone shed some light for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your jquery selector does seem to have a typo. `let select2 = $('form select[name="methodology_id"]')`

Comment: yea but the goal is to rewrite the code using checkbox which I couldn't achieve.